# Dependency issue while installing Nagios plugins

Tags: monitoring, redhat, nagios, rhel6, centreon

I have a dependency problem while installing nagios-plugins :

```
yum install nagios-plugins-all

...

--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/sensors for package: nagios-plugins-sensors-1.4.15-7.el6.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nagios-plugins-sensors-1.4.15-7.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: /usr/bin/sensors
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

OS :

- RHEL 6.1

Installed packages :

- nagios.i686 3.2.3-3.el6.rf
- nagios-plugins.i686 1.4.15-7.el6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sensors` is part of lm-sensors package.
You should be able to install it with simple

```
yum install lm_sensors
```

Then try installing nagios again.